# Can I send a website values?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wish to create an extension that will send to a target website some information.  It's not enough that I be able to inject or display information locally.  The information needs to be readable by the webserver itself.  So that, for example, a PHP script could check for this particular variable/value, and then choose what content to display itself as a result.

Is it possible to do this?  It needs to work across unique domains (not just unique sub-domains).  My browser already sends (for example) the user agent to a website.  I just want the extension to send just a little more information to the target website, for it to do with it as it pleases.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using Chrome's webRequest API, in a background script:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var headers = details.requestHeaders;
    var i = headers.length;
    headers[i] = {'name': 'new_header', 'value': 'header_value' }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

You can see this header included in php with the code:

```
<?php
  foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can communicate from the content-script and from the background page as well.

You can use the various jQuery methods to send data to the server and recieve a response:

1. [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
2. [jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Can these be done early in the load process?  That is, before the website you have visited does any of its main script processing?

Comment: you control when things happen (i.e. onnavigate event) or using the content script you can decide when to the load the script (look at the google manifest file documenation) however you cannot stop the browser from loading, this means you can start sending the data before the page is processed, but you have no way to stop the page processing until you get a response, this means the page may or maynot be loaded by the time you get the response..